# Java Generic Parameters across Dependent Java Types

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface Type that represents a metatype of data. The  parameter indicates the Java type that will be used to represent the data:

```
public interface Type<J> {
    boolean isAssignableFrom(@NotNull Type ts);

    /**
     * Gets the Java class of the representation of this type.
     */
    Class<? extends J> getValueType();
}
```

I also have a value interface that represents an instance of that type:

```
public interface Value<T extends Type> {
    <E> E get();

    @NotNull
    T getType();
}
```

What I'd like is to have the `Value` interface enforce the parameter declared on the `Type` interface. In other words, I want the `get()` method to declare that its return type MUST be within the bounds of `<J>`. But I cannot come up with any way to do this without adding `<J>` to the `Value` interface:

```
public interface Value<J, T extends Type<J>> {
    J get();

    @NotNull
    T getType();
}
```

Is there any way to make `get()` reference its `Type`'s bounded parameter without adding it to the `Value` interface? It's making the code really a lot more complex than I'd like.

So imagine `NumericType` which is a simple type to represent numbers in the system (there are more complex dynamic types that don't exist except at runtime, that's the joy of metaprogramming):

```
/** A static type representing some kind of number. */
public class NumericType implements Type<BigDecimal>
{
    public static final NumericType NUMERIC_TYPE = new NumericType();


    public boolean isAssignableFrom(@NotNull Type t)
    {
        // logic here
    }

    public Class<BigDecimal> getValueType() {
        return BigDecimal.class;
    }
}
```

It tells callers the Java type used to represent this type in the system. If I declare a value of `NumericType`:

```
Value<NumericType> foo;
```

I'd like to be able to have compile-time safety that `get()` will **always** return a BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal bar = foo.get();
```

That way, if I need to change the Java representation of a given Type (say, I want to make `NumericType<Number>` instead of `NumericType<BigDecimal>` the code above would fail at compile time. But how to I write `Value` such that its `get()` method declaration can reference the bounds of the `Type` bounded parameter? The `Value<J, Type<J>>` thing is really kludgy to read:

```
Value<BigDecimal, NumericType> foo;
```

I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Can you change `getType()` to return `Type<J>`?

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem. The caller can get the Java type of a `Value` by calling `getType().getJavaType()`; that's not the issue. I need to get the compiler to understand that a given `Value<T>`'s `get()` will always return a value bounded by `<T>`'s `<J>` parameter.

Comment: Java's type system is not powerful enough to do that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm. it is not possible to do that in Java.
Moreover, if the interest is to hide that a given NumericType uses BigDecimal as internal representation, it will be simpler and more robust to implement a complete abstraction of the needed operations using a dedicated object. If only those operations are used to manipulate the object then the internal representation can be changed such that the only changes are internals of this class :

1. It allows to precisely define the required operations
2. It allows easily to adjust the internal representation due to the reduced set of operations needed.

It is basic OOP concepts and KISS principle (Keep It Simple, Stupid).

```
class NumericType {
  private int value;
  public NumericType(int initial) {...}
  public NumericType add(NumericType operand) {...}
  ...
}
```

then it can be used like this

```
NumericType bar = new NumeicType(1);
bar = bar.add(new NumericType(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what wildcards are invented for. Use "? extends" wildcard:
    `public interface Value<J, T extends Type<? extends J>> {...}`